# Speaker is not working during phone calls

Tags: audio, sony-xperia-z

I've a Sony Xperia Z smartphone and I recently updated Android from 4.3.x to 4.4.4. Ever since that I'm unable to hear people when making phone calls, except when I enable the free-speech button (where the side-speaker is used).

Applications like Youtube are affected as well.

I already toyed around with sound settings and, after seeing a notification about a headset being connected to the phone (which is not the case), plugging my earphones in and out, without success. For the record: Sound is played through the ear phones the moment they're plugged-in.

I also never saw that notification again. IIRC the notification had the 'Smart Connect' icon, but I'm not sure about it.

Sony support told me to use the repair functionality of their software which does not work (Something something update routine error 2003).

Hope someone can solve this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I completely forgot about asking this question until someone upvoted it. (Thank you).

I 'fixed' it by sending my Xperia to Sony after another defect occured (headphone jack didn't recognize when something was plugged-in). Apparently whatever was wrong with the headphone jack caused them to switch out the smartphone.

I had the same headset and the same android version on that smartphone for some time and it worked without a problem. So whatever was wrong was most probably either a hardware problem or an error that occured during the upgrade procedure (maybe something wasn't installed correctly).